# scrollViewの点の色を変えたい

Tags: swift, ios, swift4

下記のサイトを見てスクロールビューを作成しています。下記のサイトでは背景をオレンジに変えていますが、この点の色を変えることはできないのでしょうか。

```
self.scrollView.tintColor = UIColor.black
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

など試してみたのですが、できませんでした。

[UIPageControlの表示　Swift Docs](https://sites.google.com/a/gclue.jp/swift-docs/ni-yinki100-ios/uikit/uipagecontrollerno-biao-shi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ページ切り替えのドットを表示しているのは、`UIScrollView`ではなく、`UIPageControl`の方です。引用記事のタイトルも「UIPageControlの表示」となっていますよね?

[`UIPageControl`のドキュメント](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol)を調べてみてください。

「ドット」のカラーを変更するだけなら、公開プロパティが用意されています。

[`var pageIndicatorTintColor: UIColor?`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol/1621239-pageindicatortintcolor)
[`var currentPageIndicatorTintColor: UIColor?`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol/1621233-currentpageindicatortintcolor)

```
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = 〜
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = 〜
```

など、試してみてください。標準の`UIPageControl`の色違い、と言う感じに表示したい場合は、`pageIndicatorTintColor`の方は、透明色にしたほうがいいでしょう。

Comment: なるほど、気づかなかったです。ありがとうございます